# How to get into the single user mode in Linux VM in Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Can anyone help me to  get into the single user mode in Linux VM, Google Cloud.

I have tried to change the grub setting in `"/etc/default/grub" as " GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0 ro single"` but no luck.

```
[root@test-linux admin]# cat /etc/default/grub
GRUB_TIMEOUT=100
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_TERMINAL="serial console"
GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND="serial --speed=38400"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="crashkernel=auto console=ttyS0,38400n8 elevator=noop"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0 ro single"
[root@test-linux admin]#
```

Comment: Have you tried to follow my steps?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my steps below:

0. create VM instance (optional):

```
$ gcloud compute instances create instance-1 --zone us-central1-a  --machine-type=e2-medium --network=default  --tags=ubuntu  --image-family=ubuntu-1804-lts --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud
```

1. [enable](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#gcloud) serial console:

```
$ gcloud compute instances add-metadata instance-1 --metadata serial-port-enable=TRUE --zone us-central1-a
```

2. SSH into VM instance:

```
$ gcloud compute ssh instance-1 --zone us-central1-a
```

3. modify the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg` an set it as `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0 ro single"`, then run update-grub2:

```
instance-1:~$ cat /etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg
# CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0.1
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.1
# old
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0"
# new
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0 ro single"
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

instance-1:~$ sudo update-grub2 
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1021-gcp
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1021-gcp
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

4. reboot VM instance:

```
instance-1:~$ sudo reboot
```

5. [connect](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#connectserialconsole) to VM instance through serial console:

```
...
[  OK  ] Started Wait for Network to be Configured.
[  OK  ] Reached target Network is Online.
[  OK  ] Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
         Starting Availability of block devices...
[  OK  ] Started Availability of block devices.
You are in rescue mode. After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view
system logs, "systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" or "exit"
to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(or press Control-D to continue): 
root@instance-1:~# runlevel
N 1
root@instance-1:~#
```

6. when you done remove the single user flag from grub, run the `update grub2` command and reboot:

```
root@instance-1:~# cat /etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg
# CLOUD_IMG: This file was created/modified by the Cloud Image build process
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0.1
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0.1
# old
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0"
# new
#GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="console=ttyS0 ro single"
GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_TERMINAL=console

root@instance-1:~# update-grub2
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-1021-gcp
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-1021-gcp
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done

root@instance-1:~# reboot
```

7. [disable](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console#disable_access) serial console:

```
$ gcloud compute instances add-metadata instance-1 --metadata=serial-port-enable=FALSE --zone us-central1-a
```

Do not forget to disable serial console when you done:

> **Caution**: The interactive serial console does not support IP-based access restrictions such as IP whitelists. If you enable the
> interactive serial console on an instance, clients can attempt to
> connect to that instance from any IP address. Anybody can connect to
> that instance if they know the correct SSH key, username, project ID,
> zone, and instance name. Use firewall rules to control access to your
> network and specific ports.**